# 'ILinkService' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#

I have the following extension:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddLinkService<T>(this IServiceCollection services, T linkService) where T : ILinkService {

  services.AddTransient<ILinkService, typeof(linkService)>();    

  // Extra Code   

  return services;

}
```

But I get the error:

> 'ILinkService' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

The method AddTransient signature is:

```
AddTransient(Type serviceType, Type implementationType)
```

Basically I need end with the following:

```
services.AddTransient<ILinkService, LinkService>();
```

Where LinkService is the following class:

```
public class LinkService : ILinkService { }
```

But I need to pass LinkService as is defined on another library which uses the extension.

Comment: `typeof(linkService)` looks strange to me. `linkService.GetType()` looks better to me, but on the other hand, I don't think you can specify a Generic parameter during runtime.

Comment: That's not the signature of the method you're calling since it has two arguments, it looks like you want `services.AddTransient<ILinkService, T>();`? If you want to call the non-generic version then `services.AddTransient(typeof(ILinkService), linkService.GetType())`.

Comment: @Lee when using `services.AddTransient<ILinkService, T>();` I get the error `The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TImplementation' in the generic type or method 'ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddTransient<TService, TImplementation>`

Comment: @MiguelMoura - Add a `class` constraint to `T`: `where T : ILinkService, class`.

Comment: `AddTransient(Type serviceType, Type implementationType)` it not used you are using `AddTransient<,>()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Incorrect usage of type arguments and `typeof` keyword.

`typeof(MyType)` keyword lets you to assign a run-time reference to a type available at compile-time. It can be an actual type (`MyType`) or a type argument like in your case (`T`).

In your case you don't need it.

Replace this line:

`services.AddTransient<ILinkService, typeof(linkService)>();`

with

`services.AddTransient<ILinkService, T>();`

2. Insufficient generic type arguments constraints.

You're calling the method with this signature:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddTransient<TService, TImplementation>(
  this IServiceCollection services)
  where TService : class
  where TImplementation : class, TService
```

It is generic and has constraints on it's type arguments. When it is called from another generic method with type arguments being re-used (like in your case), the constraints should not be weakened.

Replace

`where T : ILinkService`

with

`where T : class, ILinkService`

Comment: I tried that before and got the error: The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TImplementation' in the generic type or method 'ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddTransient<TService, TImplementation>

Comment: @Selvin Now I get 'ILinkService' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Comment: @MiguelMoura Try to replace `where T : ILinkService` with `where T : class, ILinkService`